# how to solve ordinary-differential equation $\frac{dA}{dt}=-(a-bp)-\alpha\beta t^{\beta-1}A$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

im currently reading a paper and there is this differential equation (which already has a final solution)

$\frac{dA}{dt}=-(a-bp)-\alpha\beta t^{\beta-1}A$

note: a, b, p, $\alpha, \beta$ are parameters with no range. while 0 < t < any point at postive direction of x-axis

i identified it as **first-order linear differential equation**.

after multiplied both sides of the differential equation with the integrating factor and integrating both side, i got

$A=-(a-bp)e^{\alpha t^{\beta}}\int e^{\alpha t^{\beta}} dt $

i get stuck at solving the integral so after getting some help from here [solution of the integral](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4402312/how-to-integrate-int-e-alpha-t-beta-dt), i found out that $\int e^{\alpha t^{\beta}}$ doesn't has a closed-form solution, **but the final solution of this ODE is**

$A=-(a-bp)e^{\alpha t^{\beta}}[t+\frac{\alpha}{\beta+1} e^{-\alpha t^{\beta}}]+C_1e^{-\alpha t^{\beta}} $

im questioning about my method of solving this ODE right now, am i identified it wrong? cause the final equation doesn't indicate an open-form solution, but i can't think of any other method for this problem.

any hints or answer would be helpful, thank you.

Comment: @Moo yes, the equation (both ODE and the final solution of the ODE) is written correctly based on the paper

Comment: @Moo here's the link https://www.researchgate.net/publication/333379519_A_Pharmaceutical_Inventory_Model_for_Varying_Deteriorating_Items_with_Price_Sensitive_Demand_and_Partial_Backlogging_Under_the_Effect_of_Learning the ODE is on page 7, and the solution is right on the next page

Comment: Try to reduce the number of constants. For example, a + b + x = 5 (very random but you'll get the point) where a and b are constants. Now just do a+b = C. Try applying a similar method to ur prob. It might do wonders

Comment: @cynews09 I think the solution in that paper is not correct, as you can check by substituting into the differential equation. The answer should include the (incomplete) [Gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function) which results from your integral $\int e^{\alpha t^\beta}$